# Google Chrome audit on caching

Tags: php, apache, http, caching

If I run an audit on my sites with Google Chrome, I get this message in the *Leverage browser caching* section:

> The following resources are missing a
>   cache expiration. Resources that do
>   not specify an expiration may not be
>   cached by browsers:

A list of all the pictures follows. I get a similar notice in *Leverage proxy caching*:

> Consider adding a "Cache-Control:
>   public" header to the following
>   resources:

Apart from pictures, I also get a notice about HTML, CSS and JavaScript files:

> The following resources are explicitly
>   non-cacheable. Consider making them
>   cacheable if possible:

Its funny because I've worked hard to cache all static contents (except for pictures, where I just left Apache's default settings). Firefox does indeed store all these items in cache.

Is there anything I should improve in my HTTP headers?

---

Here's the complete header set of some items as loaded after removing the browser caché. Pictures use default settings I didn't really check before, the rest should be cachéd for three hours. I can set headers with both `.htaccess` and `PHP`.

## PNG

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 31 Jul 2010 12:46:14 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Mar 2010 21:40:54 GMT
Etag: "c48024-230-4821a15d6c580"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 560
Keep-Alive: timeout=4
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/png
```

## HTML

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 31 Jul 2010 12:46:13 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.11
Expires: Sat, 31 Jul 2010 15:46:13 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=10800, s-maxage=10800, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Wed, 24 Mar 2010 20:30:36 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=4
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15
```

## CSS

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 31 Jul 2010 12:48:21 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.11
Expires: Sat, 31 Jul 2010 15:48:21 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=10800, s-maxage=10800, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Mar 2010 21:40:12 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=4
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/css
```

## JavaScript

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 31 Jul 2010 12:48:21 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.11
Expires: Sat, 31 Jul 2010 15:48:21 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=10800, s-maxage=10800, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Mar 2010 21:40:12 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=4
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
```

---

## Update

I've tested Jumby's suggestion and set my CSS's expire to 1 year:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=31536000, s-maxage=31536000, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:4198
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Mon, 02 Aug 2010 20:48:56 GMT
Expires:Tue, 02 Aug 2011 20:48:56 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Last-Modified:Thu, 18 Mar 2010 20:40:12 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) PHP/5.3.1
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.1
```

However, Chrome still claims "*explicitly non-cacheable*".

Comment: Just got a similar problem, whatever I do, chrome audit keeps bugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 hour expiry might not be enough "time" for the yslow/page speed stuff and they might complain about it. I have seen this with static content on my sites with 4 hour expiration & yslow (havent tried with google's stuff).

Most of those want versioned static content with LONG expire times (like 1 year); see [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires)

Comment: I've tried your suggestion (see my edited post) but Chrome still complains. I'm tempted to just ignore it and use another tool. Even Chrome loads the docs from caché when I visit the page later.

Comment: Try eliminating/modifying headers to see if you can determine which is causing it. I would try with Cache-Control:public . Also, checkout redbot.org and enter in a URL for your static content.

Comment: http://redbot.org is a great tool (and it also explains why "Cache-Control: public" is unnecessary in most cases). I need to have a closer look at static content caching but I believe Chrome's Audit feature is just buggy.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the "must-revalidate" part of your cache-control directive. Get rid of that, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes, but why is it a problem? Is Chrome's message misleading? incorrect? Subtly correct?

Comment: I can verify that removing `must-revalidate` stops Chrome audit from complaining about those endpoints being uncacheable.  This doesn't seem to make sense given the behavior described in the RFC.  I wonder how Chrome handles `must-revalidate`…

Answer (score 0):

I just got a similar issue, I discovered the very same setup and code produces a chrome audit warning when trying on my test server at 127.0.0.1, but not on the real server with a real DNS name.