# Why does Chrome DevTools say my static resource is explicitly non-cacheable while mapped with Spring's mvc:resources?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, browser-cache, static-resource

I'm using Spring MVC 4, and handle static resources as follow (cache for one year):

```xml
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" cache-period="31556926" />
```

I have an `app.js` file in my `static` folder. When launching an [audit with the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#audits), the `app.js` file appears in the following section:

> The following resources are explicitly non-cacheable. Consider making them cacheable if possible:
>       app.js

The response headers for this static file request are:

```
Date: Mon, 23 Feb 2015 18:02:49 GMT
Expires: Tue, 23 Feb 2016 23:51:36 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31556926, must-revalidate
```

Are my static resources well cached by browsers? Why is the Chrome DevTools telling me that `app.js` is explicitly non-cacheable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen similar oddities with chrome audit and it seems the consensus is that Chrome audit might be buggy:

[Google Chrome audit on caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378177/google-chrome-audit-on-caching)

Besides the other answers in that referenced question I have two additional theories that I haven't tested thoroughly but I think might cause the issue:

**1) Cookies**

When you have cookies being passed along with the image which happens quite frequently with Java applications (jsession and various other cookies perhaps set in filters). The problem is that you didn't seem to show us any cookies in your header. Also newer versions of chrome audit typically complain about this as a separate error.

**2) Dynamically requesting content via DOM change**

Some Javascript library particularly ACE edit will dynamically add fonts and or Javascript (aka AMD) and occasionally add query parameters to the URL. This seems to confuse chrome audit. So perhaps your `app.js` is being added dynamically through some other Javascript (ie adding a `<script...src= ></script>` element) and/or adding query parameters to the URL?

**UPDATE**

I think I know what your particular issues is. Chrome audit does not like `must-revalidate` and unfortunately when you specify a `cache-period` greater than `0` the Spring `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` will always add the `must-revalidate` to the cache control header. If you don't set `cache-period` (it will be -1) then Spring will still do caching headers but will not do `must-revalidate` (however no `max-age` leads to another audit error message of *The following resources are missing a cache expiration. Resources that do not specify an expiration may not be cached by browsers:*).

Unfortunately you will either need to write a filter to remove the `must-revalidate` or create your own version of `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` [probably extending and overriding `cacheForSeconds`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/WebContentGenerator.java#330).

Some other options are to use an asset pipeline library like [Wro4J](https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/) or uploading the app.js to your CDN.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have not been able to find the other question you linked at the time I was posting this one. One last question though: is it only the Chrome audit tool that behaves like that, or the whole Chrome browser? If it's only the Chrome audit tool, it doesn't really matter, as long as browsers cache my static resources as needed ;)

Comment: I believe it is just the audit tool because if you look at the devtools network tabs you can see chrome doing the right thing and even if you refresh you get a 304 not modifed for the spring resource handler.